# Canonical treatment of thermalization of two gases at different temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics, scattering, non-equilibrium

I'd like to understand the thermalization process when two gases of different species and different temperatures are allowed to mix in an insulated container, interacting only through an elastic scattering process.  What is the time-dependence of the average energy per kinetic mode for each gas? How does this depend on the scattering cross-section?  (I am most interested in gases that primarily scatter in the forward direction.)  Is there a relevant Boltzmann equation?

A reference to the canonical treatment of this problem would be sufficient and very much appreciated.