# Thermalization of two gases at different temperatures

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

Consider a box with partitions $A$ and $B$ each filled with a (possibly different) gas at temperature $T_A$ and $T_B$, and is separated by an adiabatic barrier. Each partition is in thermal equilibrium.

Is it possible to derive the time evolution of the partitions temperature in case:

1. The barrier becomes transparent, allowing energy flow through radiation, but no matter flow.
2. The barrier disappears, allowing matter flow.

I am looking for the evolution of the internal energies of the gases in each partition in time, not just the final Temperature after new equilibrium is reached.

I welcome any hint or, preferably, suggested reading.

---

I found this similar [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208338/canonical-treatment-of-thermalization-of-two-gases-at-different-temperatures), unanswered.

I am acquainted with [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling), but I don't think it applies in these situations.

Comment: Yes, but to do this, you need use the partial differential equations of fluid mechanics, heat transfer, and mass transfer, recognizing that, during the change, the gases in the partitions are not homogeneous in temperature, velocity, density, and, in the case of two different gases, composition.

Comment: @ChetMiller, thanks for the comment. I am okay with a simple model. What if I focus on case 1 only, is there a simple PDE to consider? I don't know fluid mechanics

Comment: It depends on what you mean by simple.  You would have to consider the absorption and re-re-radiation of photons by the differential. parcels of gas comprising the combined  whole of the gases in the two chambers.  This would be like an atmospheric greenhouse model.

Comment: @ChetMiller, simple like considering each gas to be a black body radiating only to each other (no wall leakage). Is this too simplistic or too unsound t have been studied before?

Comment: I don't think they can be considered black bodies.

Comment: @ChetMiller, so would you advise me to look at [wikipedia's green house model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealized_greenhouse_model)? What would you advise as a starting point?

Comment: Okay, I don't think [wikipedia's green house model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealized_greenhouse_model) is modelling the same problem I am considering. It admits an extrinsic source of power (the Sun) and leakage. Furthermore, Earth's surface and atmosphere are not evolving to thermal equilibrium. Any other suggestion is welcome.